# VirtualDub audio playback lag

Tags: virtualdub

In VirtualDub's capture mode, you can tick an option "Enable audio playback" which will play audio along with your video feed.

I'd like to hear sound while I play a game.

However, enabling audio playback causes severe framerate issues and makes the video run at something like 5 FPS and the game unplayable. It's awful.

Any known fixes for this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will get a better help at the VirtualDub forum: http://forums.virtualdub.org/index.php